# post a combination value instead of many drop-down values

Tags: drop-down-menu, datagrid

i am working on a project where a clerk like professional will make/edit classes time table for educational institute.
so in a day-period cell there are many drop-downs for selecting teacher, classroom/lab, batch of students, subject etc.
and this whole combination of values can be repeated many places in the grid.
so i want to post a single value combining all these 4-5 values through POST data in FORM for that cell location.
what approach should i use?

**EDIT:**

Oh! Yes, i am actually using PHP and angularjs and this is sample code in html

```
<table border="1" width="90%" height="90%" style="margin:10px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Day
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="hour in chours">
                    {{hour.name}}
                    <br>
                    {{hour.stime}}--{{hour.etime}}
                    <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="hour.noclass" /> No class {{hour.noclass}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="day in weekdays">
                <td>
                    {{day.name}}
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="hour in day.hours">
                    <div ng-show="hour.noclass=='false'" name="cell[{{day.name}}][{{hour.name}}][]">
                        <select name="cars">
                            <option ng-model="dd" ng-repeat="sub in subjects">{{sub.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                        {{dd}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
```

and this is in js file

```
    var App = angular.module('tteditApp',[]);
App.controller('editCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.chours=[
            {'name':'1','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'true'},
            {'name':'2','stime':'855','etime':'950','noclass':'true'},
            {'name':'3','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'4','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'5','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'6','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'7','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'8','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'9','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'},
            {'name':'10','stime':'800','etime':'855','noclass':'false'}];
    $scope.subjects=[{'name':'CLOUD'},{'name':'CC'},{'name':'ISS'},{'name':'DCT'},{'name':'DMW'},{'name':'VLSI'},{'name':'SEMINAR'},{'name':'PROJECT'},{'name':'WEB DEV'}];
    $scope.weekdays=[{'name':'Monday','hours':$scope.chours},{'name':'Tuesday','hours':$scope.chours},
                    {'name':'Wednesday','hours':$scope.chours},{'name':'Thursday','hours':$scope.chours},{'name':'Friday','hours':$scope.chours}
                    ,{'name':'Saturday','hours':$scope.chours}];
  });
```

Comment: Which facilities do you use? Which language, framework etc. What have you tried. Ideally provide some code.

Comment: i have edited my question..